# Best way to modify HTML structure for different screens (possibly with media-queries)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am building a simple page with React and Reactstrap. It is rendered in a asymmetrical way so for three Rows on the screen the scheme is 1) Img - Text 2) Text - img 3) Img - Text.
The problem is when the screen is reduced because the text wraps under the image, resulting in a double text view between the first and the second row which is bad to see. How to fix it? 
 In CSS I think it is not possible since media queries cannot alter the HTML structure and, in this case, it is not simply to hide an element but to change its disposition.

JSX

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import about1 from '../images/aboutstile1.jpg';
import about2 from '../images/aboutstile2.jpg';
import about3 from '../images/aboutstile3.jpg';
// import about3 from '../images';
// import about4 from '../images';
import './about.css';
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody,
    CardTitle, CardSubtitle, Button, CardImgOverlay } from 'reactstrap';

export default class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div className="main">

          </div>
          <br/>
          <br/>
        <Container className="cont">      
            <Row>      
                <Col className="about_tile">
                    <img className="about_tile_img" src={about2} alt=""/>
                </Col>
                    <Col className="about_text">
                        <h2>Executive Recruitment</h2>
                        <p>REC Consulting provides a full range of solution
                        to hire the most complex managerial figures a business needs. Thanks to
                        specific enquires on the type of leadership of the candidate we will know beforehand if
                        the profile is going to be the right leader in the team in the company.</p>    
                    </Col>          
            </Row>
            <br/>
            <Row>
            <Col className="about_text">
                        <h2>Technical Expertise</h2>
                        <p>REC Consulting provides a full range of solution
                        to hire the most complex managerial figures a business needs. Thanks to
                        specific enquires on the type of leadership of the candidate we will know beforehand if
                        the profile is going to be the right leader in the team in the company.</p>    
                    </Col>         
            <Col className="about_tile">
                    <img className="about_tile_img" src={about3} alt=""/>
                </Col>  
            </Row>
            <br/>
            <Row>      
            <Col className="about_tile">
                    <img className="about_tile_img" src={about1} alt=""/>
                </Col>
                    <Col className="about_text">
                        <h2>Executive Recruitment</h2>
                        <p>REC Consulting provides a full range of solution
                        to hire the most complex managerial figures a business needs. Thanks to
                        specific enquires on the type of leadership of the candidate we will know beforehand if
                        the profile is going to be the right leader in the team in the company.</p>    
                    </Col>    
            </Row>
            </Container>
            <br/>
            <br/>    
        </div>      
    )   
  }
}
```

CSS

```
.main {
    height: 26rem;
    background-image: url('../images/abouts7.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 9%;
  }



/* .cont {
    max-width: 100rem;
} */

.about_tile {
    width: 400px;
    height: 320px;
}

.about_tile_img {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: turquoise;
    border-radius: 25px;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 320px
}

.about_text {
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[image: correct view]

[image: incorrect view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of altering the column order in the html, change the flex direction for every other row.

With bootstrap 4 you can use the helper class `flex-row-reverse` on every other `<div class="row flex-row-reverse">...</div>`.

I am not familiar with JSX so not 100% on how you would actually add the class, but the generated html should look something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      image
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row flex-row-reverse">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      image
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      text
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: unluckily seems it is not working in reactStrap...the documentation appear not to be complete with the reverse property :S

Comment: have you tried `<Row className="flex-row-reverse">`

Comment: oh wait it works!!! now it displays reverse! still, how can I display this class only under 767px width of the viewport? I would not like to add jquery just to remove one class in the whole dom...

Comment: You dont need to do anything - under 767px, you dont have any columns, it should look like how you want on mobile, 1 column with image on top of text, as per the order in the html. The reverse class only effects the view on tablet and up (where you actually have columns to order)

Comment: Note that the html always has the image as the first column in a row, and the `flex-row-reverse` class is applied to every other row, to get the alternating effect on 768px and up

Comment: yeah...i hope its becasue it's late an I am tired...it totally works obviously :)! I was almost going to make a contructor method to remove the property if the screen was under 767px! thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Ha, no problem! Glad i could help you